# Custom config file for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Very new to CodeIgniter, trying to create a custom config file to load special variables into my application.

in `application/config/` I created `custom.php` and placed the following code in that file:

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$gender = array ('male','female'); 

?>
```

I then opened up `application/config/autoload` and altered the following code:

```
$autoload['config'] = array();

/* TO: */ 

$autoload['config'] = array('custom');
```

I refresh my application and see this error:

```
Your application/config/custom.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.
```

I opened up some of the default config files and don't see a configuration array? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use

```
$config['gender']= array ('male','female');
```

instead of

```
$gender = array ('male','female');
```

For fetching config item

```
$this->config->item('item_name');
```

Where `item_name` is the `$config` array index you want to retrieve.

Docs : [**CodeIgniter User Guide 2.x**](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/config.html)  [**CodeIgniter User Guide 3.x**](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html?#fetching-config-items)

Answer (score 10):

**Creating custom config file**:
Add a new file under “application/config/” with named “custom_config.php” (or give any name) and add below code

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
//adding config items.
$config['gender'] = array('female', 'male');
```

**Loading custom config file** :- After create custom config file we need to load it get it’s items. for load custom config we have two ways

*** Manual loading:- we can manual load config file in controller/model like

```
$this->config->load('custom_config'); //or instead your file name.
```

*** Autoloading :- for auto load config file go to “application/config/autoload.php” and add code in $autoload[‘config’]

```
$autoload['config'] = array('custom_config'); //or instead your file name.
```

Comment: $gender = $this->config->item('gender'); // return array

Comment: Also, you can use $this->load->config('custom_config') for loading your config file.

Answer (score 2):

## CodeIgniter 3

### Step 1: Create the custom configuration file

#### `/path/to/codeigniter/application/config/custom.php`

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['server'] = array (
    'host'      => 'example.com',
    'public_ip' => '93.184.216.34'
    );
?>
```

### Step 2: Load the custom configuration file

This can be done either inside a model or a controller.

```php
// load the configuration file
$this->config->load('custom');

// retrieve the content of a specific configuration
$server = $this->config->item('server');

// $server is now set
echo $server['host']; // example.com
```