# codeigniter use of variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is that I have a lot of long url links that have to be repeated on various pages of the site, so what I want to do is put each url equal to a variable and then use the variables to enter the urls. I could do this in the $data array inside a controller function but I don't want to clutter the controller function with a very long and messy list. So I have set up a file with variables equal to the urls and tried to introduce it at the top of my template (so it will be included in every page, the variables will be declared on every page and can be used on every page).

I've tried $this->load->file('filepath/filename',true) but I get an 'undefined variable' error. I've tried including the file under views and then doing $this->load->view('filepath/filename'.''.true) but again the variable is undefined.

Maybe I'm setting about this all the wrong way but can anybody give me a steer.

Comment: If these are all static values you know ahead of time; how about a config file or a database table?

Comment: A thread on custom config files in CI. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810891/custom-config-file-for-codeigniter

Comment: I did think of using a database but I have had experience in the past of databases 'refusing' some characters and a url can contain a wide variety of characters so I was reluctant. I like the idea of a custom config file and will probably go that route. Many thanks for contributions.